# Finding duplicate entries in SQL DB and show only one

Tags: sql, database

I have a table like this:

```
   Name    |   Text
-----------------------
 ALM_1234  |  Language1
 ALM_1234  |  Language2
 ALM_4321  |  Language1
 ALM_9876  |  Language1
```

I need a SQL query for showing just one entry of duplicate entries with one text. It doesn't matter which of the two texts are displayed.
Like this:

```
   Name    |   Text
-----------------------
 ALM_1234  |  Language1
 ALM_4321  |  Language1
 ALM_9876  |  Language1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need them to be unique over just one column or multiple?

Comment: Use Distinct as, `Select Distinct * from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group By` and `Min/Max` aggregate

```
Select Name,Min(Text) as Text
From yourtable
Group by Name
```

Comment: why the `Min/Max` just curious?

Comment: @Adam - Because OP has mentioned *It doesn't matter which of the two texts are displayed.*

Comment: @Prdp Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` as it will drop all but the first of any other columns

```
select name, text from table group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DISTINCT` command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Which dbms is that?

Answer (score 0):

use having in your query such as this query:

```
Select Text From yourtable Group by Text having count(*)>1
```

if you would like to find the duplicate query you should use this one:

```
select Name , Text from Yourtable group by Name , Text having count(*)>1
```

good luck

Comment: Parentheses enclosing the having clause.

Comment: it is ok now by removing parentheses

Comment: Better. But not what OP wants, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

distinct clause will work

```
select distinct name,text from table
```

Comment: No what OP wants, seince it will return all 4 rows.